# Custom code completion to Visual Studio Code?

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code, code-completion

I have a definition (below) file for a JavaScript library.
How can I hook it up to **Visual Studio Code code completion**?

It has the following format:

```
{
    "!name": "SomeLibrary",
    "someMethod" : 
    {
        "!doc" : "Description of some method.",
        "!type" : "fn(someParameter: someType) -> someReturnType"
    },
    "SomeClass" :
    {
        "!doc" : "Description of some class.",
        "someOtherMethod" :
        {
            "!doc" : "Description of some other method.",
            "!type" : "fn(someParameter: someType) -> someReturnType"
        }
    }
}
```

---

Bonus question: What is the name of this format at all?

---

**UPDATE:** I found out that I should create a [**Typescript definition file**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html), but I really don't know how to convert it from this file I have. Is this a standard format at all?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to create is called a [snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets):

> You can define your own snippets, either global snippets or snippets for a specific language. To open up a snippet file for editing, select **User Snippets** under **File > Preferences** (**Code > Preferences on macOS**) and select the language (by [language identifier](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers)) for which the snippets should appear or create a new global snippet (**New Global Snippets file...**).

Since snippets themselves are defined as JSON, your example could get a bit messy, but basically it would look like this:

```
{
    "You Interface Definition": {
        "prefix": "idef",
        "body": [
          "{",
          "\t\"!name\": \"<LIBRARY_NAME>\",",
          "\t\"<METHOD_NAME>\" : ",
          "\t\t{",
          "\t\t\"!doc\" : \"<DESCRIPTION>\",",
          "\t\t\"!type\" : \"fn(<PARAMETER_NAME>: <PARAMETER_TYPE>) -> <RETURN_TYPE>\"",
          "\t\t},",
          "\t\"<CLASS_NAME>\" : {",
          "\t\t\"!doc\" : \"<DESCRIPTION>\",",
          "\t\t\"<METHOD_NAME>\" : {",
          "\t\t\t\"!doc\" : \"<DESCRIPTION>\",",
          "\t\t\t\"!type\" : \"fn(<PARAMETER_NAME>: <PARAMETER_TYPE>) -> <RETURN_TYPE>\"",
          "\t\t}",
          "\t}",
          "}",
        ]
    },
}
```

*Note that I'm using `\t` rather than spaces, since that will respect a user's indentation settings*

Now, once you type the prefix `idef` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> the snippet will expand. You can add tab-stops with placeholder text, in case you want to change `<DESCRIPTION>` or `<PARAMETER_NAME>`. Here's a simplified example:

```
\"fn(${1:<PARAMETER_NAME>}: ${2:<PARAMETER_TYPE>}) -> ${3:<RETURN_TYPE>}\""
```

Note those parts enclosed by curly braces. Once your snippet is expanded you can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to jump between those tab-stops and modify the selected text. The same tab-stop can be repeated multiple times, should you have the need to insert the same text at multiple places.

Comment: Thanks for getting back! Perhaps I should rephrase the question, but I want code completion based on the content (!) of the json.